# proxy_pass error in class.bootstrap.php

Tags: php, proxy, config, processmaker

I am using a framework called `processmaker` and I have a problem in a class called `class.bootstrap.php`. When I try to access the framework I get a server error due to a line in this file:

```
 $config['proxy_pass'] = G::decrypt($config['proxy_pass'], 'proxy_pass');
```

The server we use is Apache and it is installed on a Windows Server 2008.

Comment: and this error message is....?

Comment: Could you provide the error message please? This will help to solve your problem much faster.